# Pull svn code using batch file windows

Tags: batch-file, svn

I am trying to write batch script for windows to pull code from svn. below is my code

```
echo Setting the directory.....
set SVNExe="C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" 
set SVNURL="https://svnserver5.in/svn/repos/test" 
set CheckOutLocation="D:\SvnCode\" 
echo %SVNExe% checkout %SVNURL% %checkOutLocation%
```

but its not working its just open command prompt and close noting happen so please help and tell me what i did worng.

Comment: can you add a pause at the end of the script so we can see what it produces before closing cmd?

Comment: The last command in the script is an `echo ...` one, that just _display_ the contents of `%SVNExe%` variable. If you want to _execute_ such a variable, just remove the `echo ` part.

Comment: @Aacini you should expand upon that and post as an answer.

Comment: thax for the help @GerhardBarnard i pause the script got problem.

Comment: thax @Aacini for suggestion of removing echo :D

Answer (score 0):

Let's first add echo off so it does not echo your commands, but only echo the results. Add a pause at the end to see the result and then remove the echo on the last commands as it will only echo your command. As mentioned in your comments by Aacini

```
@echo off
echo Setting the directory.....
set SVNExe="C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" 
set SVNURL="https://svnserver5.in/svn/repos/test" 
set CheckOutLocation="D:\SvnCode\" 
%SVNExe% checkout %SVNURL% %checkOutLocation%
pause
```